# Relation between baud rate and sampling rate and regarding simulation in Simulink

Tags: sampling, simulink

[image]I am new to the field of signal processing. So, this might be a very basic question.
Recently, I am trying to build a Heart rate sensor for a cycle. I am mod-ekg (olimex) board with TI's MSP430FG439 microcontroller. From its serial port, the board is sending some kind of pulse signal, that I have to process to find the HR. I am using Simulink for signal filtration and HR calculation.
The board sends signals at 115.200 kbps. In simulink, I have set the sample time of 0.01s.
What I observe is that the signal is dropping to 0 intermittently between high positive value.I increased the sample time value to 0.2 sec. The signal dropping has improved but I lose some features of the signal.
Can someone tell me whether there is a relation between baud rate and sample time.. whether there is a perfect sample time for my case.?

Thanks a lot in advance. Have a nice day.

PS: I am using real time data, limit set at infinity. Mostly, I capture data for 2-3 mins. So, based on the sampling rate the no. of samples would be different in each case. The picture is comparison between data at 2 sampling rates. the left one is at 0.01sec sampling rate and the right one is at 0.02sec sampling rate.

Comment: Your description is unclear.  Can you _edit your question_ to show plots of your received data in each case?  Are you capturing data over the same duration in each case (i.e., are you capturing 1000 samples at $T_s = 0.01\mathrm s$ and 5 at $T_s = 0.02\mathrm s$, or are you capturing the same number of samples in each case?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I have added one picture comparing plots at 2 different sampling rates. I am taking data for a fixed time, so based on the sampling rate the total number of samples would be different. ex. for 1 min data capture,  sample count = 6000 @ Ts = 0.01s and 3000 @ Ts= 0.2s. I would like to know, whether there is any relation between Ts and baud rate (115.2kbps for both cases).   Have a nice day.